# How to delete the value in the url string query according to the selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a filter when clicking the remove button which has its own value will remove the value in the url according to the selected value.

For example, I have a query string `brands` which contains `1,2,3`. when I click the remove 1 button then the number 1 will be removed so the remaining value is 2.3 and url become `http://www.test.com/search?brands=2,3` and if I click the remove button 3 then the number 3 will be removed and the value will only be 2. and the url will be `http://www.test.com/search?brands=2`. if i click all, the url will be like this `http://www.test.com/search?brands=`

how do i handle something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var textUrl = $('.url').text()
  var url = new URL(textUrl)
  var getBrandsValue = url.searchParams.get("brands")
  console.log(getBrandsValue)
  
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    var dataValue = $(this).data('value')
    console.log('data click => ', dataValue)
    var replaceValue = getBrandsValue.replace(dataValue, '')
    
    console.log(replaceValue)
    $('.newUrl').text("http://www.test.com/search?brands=" + replaceValue)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="url">http://www.test.com/search?brands=1,2,3</div>
  <button type="button" data-value="1">Remove 1</button>
  <button type="button" data-value="2">Remove 2</button>
  <button type="button" data-value="3">Remove 3</button>
  
  <div class="newUrl"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Split the value of `getBrandsValue` at the commas, so that you get an array of the individual numbers. Then find the one you want to remove in there and remove it, and join the array together with commas after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` is not recommended, because it may replace `1` in `10`, `11`, `12`, `21`, `31`,.... You should:

1. convert string into array (calling `.split(',')`)
2. find & remove `1` clicked element in array
3. join array back into string (calling `.join(',')`)

   ```
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var textUrl = $('.url').text()
           var url = new URL(textUrl)
           var getBrandsValue = url.searchParams.get("brands").split(',');
           console.log(getBrandsValue)

           $('button').on('click', function () {
               var dataValue = $(this).data('value')
               console.log('data click => ', dataValue)
               getBrandsValue.splice(getBrandsValue.indexOf(dataValue), 1);
               replaceValue = getBrandsValue.join(',');

               console.log(replaceValue)
               $('.newUrl').text("http://www.test.com/search?brands=" + replaceValue)
           })
       });
   ```